# Initialize dynamic property values before vue js component is initialized

Tags: vuejs2

I want to bind dynamic properties into vue js components, and want to bind composite values, but  I don't know when/where I can initialize default values. I tried created(),   at this lifecycle moment, this.$refs  is empty.

my class MyField contains more information than value itself, e.g. enabled.

the program doesn't use static properties, instead only field names are static in the template and field name is also property name. All script contents are generic and same in every template, so that it can be injected via mixins or something else like it.

```
<template>
  <enhanced-field type='text' v-model="meta$['name'].value" ... ref="name" :disabled="!meta$['name'].enabled" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() {
     return {
       meta$: new Map() // can be replaced by vuex store.
     }
   },
   created() {
      // initialize default values, but at this moment,  this.$refs is empty.
      Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((field) => {
            var v = this.meta$[field];
            if (!v) 
                this.meta$[field] = new MyField(this.$refs[field].nodeName);
        });
   },
   // ....
}
</script>
```

Updated@2021.11.25:
**Background:**
My application has a controller to submit a form and go to new page according to a static setting provided by component event handler data (the handler data are not kept as a JavaScript function but XML tags as a part of page), so data are not fetched after a page loaded but before going to this page. Generally in every page no any JavaScript functions expected, all logics are configured in page XML, in event handler of vuejs, my program try to translate handler data to JavaScript execution. My objective is migrating legacy program to vuejs-based version.

**Workaround:**
before navigate to a new page, put page data to a key-value pair variable (e.g. name it 'pending') and assign to .route object, in 'beforeRouteEnter' hook, move 'pending' data of the .route to a page level data holder, e.g. $thisPageVM.data$ (key-value pairs), after that all fields'  mounted hook try to fetch its data from this page level holder or initialize default value + put back to this page level holder. Data itself are kept at page level but at every field a computed copy kept. This page level holder is sent when a form is submitted.

there is a technical issue, field's model is computed variable 'val' but the computed variable 'val' is used before mounted hook is called, so that this.$recompute('val') is required in mounted hook to re-initialize its value. this $recompute is a hacking solution (vuejs v2).

Comment: this.$refs is only available in mounted hook, try mounted instead of created

Comment: @Mohsin Amjad it seems that cannot initialize default values at mounted hook because it is called after binding, null pointer exception still caught, before mounted DOM into the document tree, document.getElementById also doesn't work, so I don't know how many input fields defined in the template before it is mounted.

Comment: can you provide minimal codesandbox env for this issue, so that it's easy to understand what you're trying to do, 
their is pretty common way to handle multiple dynamin inputs using v-model in v-for and it works like this e.g ``` <li v-for="input in inputs">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="input.value">
  </li>``` and your input.value can have default values